# How to convert a .java file to a .class file when the .java file has a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I know how to convert a file with the `javac` command but the problem is that I have a file with a `thread.start()` so when I declare the tread with `Thread foo = new Thread(new FooClass()); foo.start();` it says

```
error: cannot find symbol
        Thread foo = new Thread(new fooClass());
                                 ^
  symbol:   class fooClass
  location: class main
1 error
```

Is there some way to compile them together so it recognizes it or to override the error or something? Because my computer cant use Eclipse it wont let me so. If you could tell me how to get this working that would be great!

Here is the full code:

Main.java:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread foo = new Thread(new fooClass());
        fooClass.start();
    }
}
```

and FooClass.java:

```
public class FooClass implements Runnable{
public void run(){

    int time=0;
    boolean isDay=true;
    while(true){
        time++;
        System.out.print("A second has passed");
        if(time==60){
            if(isDay==true){
                isDay=false;
                System.out.print("It is now night");
            }
            if(isDay==false){
                isDay=true;
                System.out.print("It is now day");
            }
        }
        }
        try{
        Thread.sleep(1);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

}
}
```

Comment: there is nopthing differen if you got threads. YOu just haven't imported the class `fooClass`I guess - but please show us the whole code.

Comment: this class won't be correct if fooClass is not a Runnable, either.  so much wrong in one line of code.

Comment: @duffymo Well, let's just assume fooClass() IS in fact a runnable, we don't know after all.

Comment: Why?  What if they also messed that up?  It's as reasonable to assume it's not, given no info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with `Thread`. It says it can't resolve the symbol `fooClass`, which must resolve to a class.

You either misspelled (hopefully, in fact) the class name or you don't have it in the classpath/on the list of files you are passing javac.

In case Google is confusing you with too many results, [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) should be a very good start in your study of how to use `javac`.

Comment: Or it's a missing import. Either way - we'd need the whole file and project structure to be certain.

Comment: ok so I know the class name is spelt right so how would i add it to the list im passing to javac?

Comment: Will you also spare a second to format it properly? It's not quite readable right now.

Comment: Don't bother, in fact; the code didn't reveal any new source of potential error. The error is as described in my answer, except that the *hopeful* reason for it has not materialized.

Comment: ok got it to work just had to put everything in a folder and used the -classpath